# CSS does not recognize child class

Tags: html, css

I found a code that work on codepen but not on my project, i'm confuse on how things working on CSS because it's my first time trying to explore CSS.

here is the code:

-HTML

```
    <label for="choice-dollar">Change Password?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice-dollar" id="choice-dollar">
    <div class="reveal-if-active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.NewPassword" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.NewPassword" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.ConfirmPassword" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

-CSS

```
.reveal-if-active {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 16px;
 transform: scale(0.8);
 transition: 0.5s;
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ & {
   opacity: 1;
   max-height: 100px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   transform: scale(1);
   overflow: visible;
 } 
}
```

The code seam to work but the problem part is on CSS the input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ &
Visual studio does not recognize this line as it should be, what am i lacking?

[image]

but works perfectly fine here on codepen https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/LEGXOK

Comment: This is not CSS - CSS does not support nesting. You were writing SCSS, and codepen was translating it for you. In CSS, you would have to have a separate rule for `.reveal-if-active`, and a separate rule for `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active`.

Comment: What should i install on my project? was SharpScss the right one?

Comment: There are three ways to do it: fix your CSS to be valid CSS, use a serverside compiler (that compiles SCSS to CSS as part of the building process), or use a clientside compiler (which is less work for you, as nothing in your project needs to change, but moves the compilation burden to the browser for each request the SCSS is used in). How to do #2 would be a separate question, and you would need to tag your project's language and tooling for it to be answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Amadan said, this is not valid CSS. It is working on codepen probably because it is using some kind of CSS pre-processor such as SASS/LESS/Stylus.

For this code to work, you should declare the CSS like this:

```
.reveal-if-active {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 16px;
 transform: scale(0.8);
 transition: 0.5s;
}

 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .reveal-if-active {
   opacity: 1;
   max-height: 100px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   transform: scale(1);
   overflow: visible;
 }
```

The `+` selector gets the element right after the checkbox, which in this case is the `div`

**update**

Given @Amadan's input, you could mantain the selector used in the example.

```
 input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
   opacity: 1;
   max-height: 100px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   transform: scale(1);
   overflow: visible;
 }
```

Comment: The original had `~`, not `+`. `~` is a valid CSS selector, and doesn't mean the same as `+`. Since it is not a part of OP's problem, it likely should not be corrected.

Comment: That is true, OP could use the `~` as well. I'll update my answer accordingly!